# How do I count record and break if values not matched?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a record with this table

```
   No  |  Part | value |
------ | ------|------ |
   1   |   A1  |   2   |
   2   |   A1  |   2   |
   3   |   A1  |   1   |
   4   |   A1  |   2   |
   5   |   A1  |   2   |
   6   |   A1  |   2   |
```

Can I count last record and break/end counting when values unmatched ?

e.g. count value equal to 2 and the result of counting is 3

Comment: *when values unmatched* ... perhaps you mean when `value` changes?

Comment: Why do you need to break (slow query/many records)? Can you show what you've got thus far?

Comment: yes @GiorgosBetsos 
because i want to get the result for calculate some function of my Web.@RalfdeKleine

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you mean counts of adjacent values that are the same.  In SQL Server 2005, you can do this using the difference of row numbers:

```
select count(*)
from (select value, (seqnum - seqnum_v), grp, count(*) as cnt
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by part order by id) as seqnum,
                   row_number() over (partition by part, value order by id) as seqnum_v
            from t
           ) t
      group by value, (seqnum - seqnum_v)
     ) t;
```

Comment: I tried this statement but it's minus total of value 2 and value 1
so the result of this statement is 5